# What is the algorithm for checking logical equivalence of specifications?

Tags: c#, .net, expression, equivalence, specification-pattern

Consider I have an audience target group defined as:

`age >= 13 && gender == Gender.Female`

or as

`gender == Gender.Female && age >= 13`

These are equivalent specifications, which differ slightly in definition. However, specifications can be hierarchical and quite complex, forming an expression tree.

Is there a performant algorithm of checking logical equivalence of expressions/specifications?

Comment: Like `a.Where(x => b.All(y => y != x))` is equal to `a.Where(x => !b.Any(y => y == x))` which is equal to `a.Except(b)`?

Comment: @Magnus, yes. In very general case it is.